How to know the top N lines JS codes that are executed most frequently in browser / nodejs? (performance profiling)
for the JS web app running in the browser / nodejs, is there any way to know the top N lines of code that are executed most frequently ? (just for performance profiling)
or what about the top N functions that are called most frequently ?

What are you planning  to get with that information ?
Most frequently calls do not necessary mean bottleneck ? What profiling insights do you hope to gain with that ?

in a multi-person collaboration js repo, a considerable part of the code is written very dynamically (or with a bad algorithm implement). and this type of code may not be optimized well by v8 turbofan. I hope to find out the most frequently executed codes and use the v8-native-syntax for performance profiling to optimize them. @ManosKounelakis

My point is just because they are most frequent called functions doesn't mean they are the bottleneck of your application. Don't look for something specific . Use the right tools to profile your code and after that identify what your bottlenecks are
